# How can I save the picture on image control in wpf?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a simple wpf application [WIA](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/08/scanning-images-in-wpf-via-wia).My app has an image control...
I was wondering how can I save the scanned picture  on my hard disk?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on the type of the `Image.Source`, assuming that you have a `BitmapSource` as in the article it should be along those lines:

```
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)image.Source));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    encoder.Save(stream);
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) object then just call [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ex6sdew.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, the question is what is the actual type of the "image control" mentioned in the OP?