# Image in RichTextBox is blurry after resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, image, richtextbox, adorner

I have a RichTextBox. I insert an image by copy + paste. I use an adorner to resize the image. The RTB will be saved while using one XAML file for the RTB text and one PNG file for each image separately.
After resizing the image by using the adorner and SAVE, the image is blurry. For each SAVE, the image gets more and more blurry - even without further resizing.
What can I do please?

```
<Window x:Name="windowRTB" x:Class="RichTextBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Name="mainPanel">
        <ToolBar Name="mainToolBar" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="{x:Null}">
            <Button Click="SaveContent" Loaded="Button_Loaded" Content="SAVE" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </ToolBar>
        <RichTextBox Name="rtb" IsDocumentEnabled="True" AcceptsTab="True" IsReadOnly="False" TextChanged="Rtb_TextChanged">
        </RichTextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    const string gc_pathAppDataXAML = @"C:\Users\RB\Documents\XAML\";
    const string gc_pathAppDataPNG = @"C:\Users\RB\Documents\PNG\";
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Rtb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Image img in rtb.FindChildren<Image>())
        {
            img.Loaded += delegate
            {
                img.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Image_PreviewMouseDown);
            };
        }
    }

    private void Image_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rtb.IsReadOnly == false)
        {
            Image img = (Image)e.OriginalSource;

            AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(img);
            if (adornerLayer != null)
            {
                adornerLayer.Add(new ResizingAdorner(img));
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveContent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveXamlPackage(gc_pathAppDataXAML + "RTB-Test" + ".xaml");
    }

    private void SaveXamlPackage(string iv_fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            //Separately saving the images
            ExtractImages();

            //Save RTB content with placeholders for the images
            TextRange range1;
            FileStream fStream1;
            range1 = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
            fStream1 = new FileStream(iv_fileName, FileMode.Create);
            range1.Save(fStream1, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
            fStream1.Close();

            //Load RichTextBox
            LoadXamlPackage(iv_fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void ExtractImages() //Separately saving the images
    {
        Image Image;
        int lv_cnt = 0;

        foreach (Block block in rtb.Document.Blocks)
        {
            if (block is Paragraph)
            {
                Paragraph paragraph = (Paragraph)block;
                foreach (Inline inline in paragraph.Inlines)
                {
                    if (inline is InlineUIContainer)
                    {
                        InlineUIContainer uiContainer = (InlineUIContainer)inline;
                        if (uiContainer.Child is System.Windows.Controls.Image)
                        {
                            lv_cnt++;
                            Image = (Image)uiContainer.Child;
                            SaveToPng(Image, gc_pathAppDataPNG + "RTB-Test".ToString() + "-" + lv_cnt + ".png");

                            Image.Source = new BitmapImage(
                            new Uri("pack://application:,,,/RichTextBox;component/RTB_Platzhalter.png"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (block is BlockUIContainer)
            {
                BlockUIContainer container = (BlockUIContainer)block;
                if (container.Child is Image)
                {
                    lv_cnt++;
                    Image = (Image)container.Child;
                    SaveToPng(Image, gc_pathAppDataPNG + "RTB-Test".ToString() + "-" + lv_cnt + ".png");

                    Image.Source = new BitmapImage(
                    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/RichTextBox;component/RTB_Platzhalter.png"));
                }
            }
        }

        void SaveToPng(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
        {
            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            SaveUsingEncoder(visual, fileName, encoder);
        }

        void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            Size visualSize = new Size(visual.ActualWidth, visual.ActualHeight);
            visual.Measure(visualSize);
            visual.Arrange(new Rect(visualSize));
            bitmap.Render(visual);
            BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
            encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

            using (FileStream stream = File.Create(fileName))
            {
                encoder.Save(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadContent()  //While creating instance of windowRTB
    {
        LoadXamlPackage(gc_pathAppDataXAML + "RTB-Test".ToString() + ".xaml");
    }

    private void LoadXamlPackage(string iv_fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            TextRange range;
            FileStream fStream;
            if (File.Exists(iv_fileName))
            {
                range = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
                fStream = new FileStream(iv_fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
                fStream.Close();
            }

            LoadImages();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void LoadImages() //Reloading of separately saved images
    {
        Image Image;
        int lv_cnt = 0;

        foreach (Block block in rtb.Document.Blocks)
        {
            if (block is Paragraph)
            {
                Paragraph paragraph = (Paragraph)block;
                foreach (Inline inline in paragraph.Inlines)
                {
                    if (inline is InlineUIContainer)
                    {
                        InlineUIContainer uiContainer = (InlineUIContainer)inline;
                        if (uiContainer.Child is System.Windows.Controls.Image)
                        {
                            lv_cnt++;
                            Image = (System.Windows.Controls.Image)uiContainer.Child;
                            Image.Source = null;
                            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(gc_pathAppDataPNG + "RTB-Test".ToString() + "-" + lv_cnt + ".png", FileMode.Open))
                            {
                                BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();
                                imageSource.BeginInit();
                                imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                                imageSource.StreamSource = fs;
                                imageSource.EndInit();
                                Image.Source = imageSource;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (block is BlockUIContainer)
            {
                BlockUIContainer container = (BlockUIContainer)block;
                if (container.Child is System.Windows.Controls.Image)
                {
                    lv_cnt++;
                    Image = (System.Windows.Controls.Image)container.Child;
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(gc_pathAppDataPNG + "RTB-Test".ToString() + "-" + lv_cnt + ".png", FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();
                        imageSource.BeginInit();
                        imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        imageSource.StreamSource = fs;
                        imageSource.EndInit();
                        Image.Source = imageSource;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void Button_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadContent();
    }
}

public class ResizingAdorner : Adorner
{
    // Resizing adorner uses Thumbs for visual elements.   
    // The Thumbs have built-in mouse input handling. 
    Thumb topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight;

    // To store and manage the adorner's visual children. 
    VisualCollection visualChildren;

    // Initialize the ResizingAdorner. 
    public ResizingAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
    {
        visualChildren = new VisualCollection(this);

        // Call a helper method to initialize the Thumbs 
        // with a customized cursors. 
        BuildAdornerCorner(ref topLeft, Cursors.SizeNWSE);
        BuildAdornerCorner(ref topRight, Cursors.SizeNESW);
        BuildAdornerCorner(ref bottomLeft, Cursors.SizeNESW);
        BuildAdornerCorner(ref bottomRight, Cursors.SizeNWSE);

        // Add handlers for resizing. 
        bottomLeft.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(HandleBottomLeft);
        bottomRight.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(HandleBottomRight);
        topLeft.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(HandleTopLeft);
        topRight.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(HandleTopRight);
    }

    // Handler for resizing from the bottom-right. 
    void HandleBottomRight(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement adornedElement = this.AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
        Thumb hitThumb = sender as Thumb;

        if (adornedElement == null || hitThumb == null) return;
        FrameworkElement parentElement = adornedElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;

        // Ensure that the Width and Height are properly initialized after the resize. 
        EnforceSize(adornedElement);

        // Change the size by the amount the user drags the mouse, as long as it's larger  
        // than the width or height of an adorner, respectively. 
        double lv_oldWidth = adornedElement.Width;
        adornedElement.Width = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width + args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
        adornedElement.Height = adornedElement.Height * adornedElement.Width / lv_oldWidth;
    }

    // Handler for resizing from the bottom-left. 
    void HandleBottomLeft(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement adornedElement = AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
        Thumb hitThumb = sender as Thumb;

        if (adornedElement == null || hitThumb == null) return;

        // Ensure that the Width and Height are properly initialized after the resize. 
        EnforceSize(adornedElement);

        // Change the size by the amount the user drags the mouse, as long as it's larger  
        // than the width or height of an adorner, respectively. 
        double lv_oldWidth = adornedElement.Width;
        adornedElement.Width = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width - args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
        adornedElement.Height = adornedElement.Height * adornedElement.Width / lv_oldWidth;
    }

    // Handler for resizing from the top-right. 
    void HandleTopRight(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement adornedElement = this.AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
        Thumb hitThumb = sender as Thumb;

        if (adornedElement == null || hitThumb == null) return;
        FrameworkElement parentElement = adornedElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;

        // Ensure that the Width and Height are properly initialized after the resize. 
        EnforceSize(adornedElement);

        // Change the size by the amount the user drags the mouse, as long as it's larger  
        // than the width or height of an adorner, respectively. 
        double lv_oldWidth = adornedElement.Width;
        adornedElement.Width = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width + args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
        adornedElement.Height = adornedElement.Height * adornedElement.Width / lv_oldWidth;
    }

    // Handler for resizing from the top-left. 
    void HandleTopLeft(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement adornedElement = AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
        Thumb hitThumb = sender as Thumb;

        if (adornedElement == null || hitThumb == null) return;

        // Ensure that the Width and Height are properly initialized after the resize. 
        EnforceSize(adornedElement);

        // Change the size by the amount the user drags the mouse, as long as it's larger  
        // than the width or height of an adorner, respectively. 
        double lv_oldWidth = adornedElement.Width;
        adornedElement.Width = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width - args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
        adornedElement.Height = adornedElement.Height * adornedElement.Width / lv_oldWidth;
    }

    // Arrange the Adorners. 
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        // desiredWidth and desiredHeight are the width and height of the element that's being adorned.   
        // These will be used to place the ResizingAdorner at the corners of the adorned element.   
        double desiredWidth = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Width;
        double desiredHeight = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Height;
        // adornerWidth & adornerHeight are used for placement as well. 
        double adornerWidth = this.DesiredSize.Width;
        double adornerHeight = this.DesiredSize.Height;

        topLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, -adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
        topRight.Arrange(new Rect(desiredWidth - adornerWidth / 2, -adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
        bottomLeft.Arrange(new Rect(-adornerWidth / 2, desiredHeight - adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));
        bottomRight.Arrange(new Rect(desiredWidth - adornerWidth / 2, desiredHeight - adornerHeight / 2, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));

        // Return the final size. 
        return finalSize;
    }

    // Helper method to instantiate the corner Thumbs, set the Cursor property,  
    // set some appearance properties, and add the elements to the visual tree. 
    void BuildAdornerCorner(ref Thumb cornerThumb, Cursor customizedCursor)
    {
        if (cornerThumb != null) return;

        cornerThumb = new Thumb();

        // Set some arbitrary visual characteristics. 
        cornerThumb.Cursor = customizedCursor;
        cornerThumb.Height = cornerThumb.Width = 10;
        cornerThumb.Opacity = 0.40;
        cornerThumb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.MediumBlue);

        visualChildren.Add(cornerThumb);
    }

    // This method ensures that the Widths and Heights are initialized.  Sizing to content produces 
    // Width and Height values of Double.NaN.  Because this Adorner explicitly resizes, the Width and Height 
    // need to be set first.  It also sets the maximum size of the adorned element. 
    void EnforceSize(FrameworkElement adornedElement)
    {
        if (adornedElement.Width.Equals(Double.NaN))
            adornedElement.Width = adornedElement.DesiredSize.Width;
        if (adornedElement.Height.Equals(Double.NaN))
            adornedElement.Height = adornedElement.DesiredSize.Height;

        FrameworkElement parent = adornedElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            adornedElement.MaxHeight = parent.ActualHeight;
            adornedElement.MaxWidth = parent.ActualWidth;
        }
    }
    // Override the VisualChildrenCount and GetVisualChild properties to interface with  
    // the adorner's visual collection. 
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return visualChildren.Count; } }
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) { return visualChildren[index]; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Helper methods for UI-related tasks.
/// </summary>
public static class TreeHelper
{
    #region find parent
    public static T TryFindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        //get parent item
        DependencyObject parentObject = GetParentObject(child);

        //we've reached the end of the tree
        if (parentObject == null) return null;

        //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
        T parent = parentObject as T;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            return parent;
        }
        else
        {
            //use recursion to proceed with next level
            return TryFindParent<T>(parentObject);
        }
    }

    public static DependencyObject GetParentObject(this DependencyObject child)
    {
        if (child == null) return null;

        //handle content elements separately
        ContentElement contentElement = child as ContentElement;
        if (contentElement != null)
        {
            DependencyObject parent = ContentOperations.GetParent(contentElement);
            if (parent != null) return parent;

            FrameworkContentElement fce = contentElement as FrameworkContentElement;
            return fce != null ? fce.Parent : null;
        }

        //also try searching for parent in framework elements (such as DockPanel, etc)
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
        if (frameworkElement != null)
        {
            DependencyObject parent = frameworkElement.Parent;
            if (parent != null) return parent;
        }

        //if it's not a ContentElement/FrameworkElement, rely on VisualTreeHelper
        return VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }

    #endregion

    #region find children

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildren<T>(this DependencyObject source) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (source != null)
        {
            var childs = GetChildObjects(source);
            foreach (DependencyObject child in childs)
            {
                //analyze if children match the requested type
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                //recurse tree
                foreach (T descendant in FindChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetChildObjects(this DependencyObject parent)
    {
        if (parent == null) yield break;

        if (parent is ContentElement || parent is FrameworkElement)
        {
            //use the logical tree for content / framework elements
            foreach (object obj in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent))
            {
                var depObj = obj as DependencyObject;
                if (depObj != null) yield return (DependencyObject)obj;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //use the visual tree per default
            int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                yield return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region find from point

    public static T TryFindFromPoint<T>(UIElement reference, Point point)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject element = reference.InputHitTest(point) as DependencyObject;

        if (element == null) return null;
        else if (element is T) return (T)element;
        else return TryFindParent<T>(element);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Instead of rendering an Image element into a RenderTargetBitmap, try to save a TransformedBitmap (that uses the original BitmapSource as its Source) with an appropriate ScaleTransform.

Comment: did you solve the problem of moving the image while you want to resize it? so, basically when you try to resize it from bottom right corner the image moves as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the code above is using size of the visual object instead of the source image size (and it content). Therefore, when you changing the size of  images in the document (doesn't matter decrease or increase in size) and then saving the document, always the saved images lost it quality.

**The solution is saving the images using original size and content.**

So, make changes to use the image source ([converting an image from the Source pointed out by @Knuspakeks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36858755/6630084) (+1)):

```
void SaveToPng(Image image, string fileName)
{
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();                
    SaveUsingEncoder(image, fileName, encoder);
}
   
void SaveUsingEncoder(Image image, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
{
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)image.Source));
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry but I don't have enough reputation to mark my question as answered. While trying to mark my question as answered, Stackoverflow tells me this: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: Ok, did it! Didn't see the hook! Sorry!!! :-)